# Accessing Partner Central Consent Url doesn't match the URl configured for the application

Tags: rest, azure, api, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to retrieve the billing data from the Partner Central through API call

But firstly i'll need some kind of a access_token

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/partner-center-authentication?tabs=dotnet-app-only%2Cdotnet-partner-consent%2Cdotnet-csp-auth%2Cdotnet-cpv-auth) I got that with executing following Powershell code

```
    $credential = Get-Credential
$token = New-PartnerAccessToken -Consent -Credential $credential -Resource https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com -ServicePrincipal
```

I will get a refresh token and can execute this Powershell code to retrieve the Token

```
$refreshToken = 'Enter the refresh token value here'

$credential = Get-Credential
$pcToken = New-PartnerAccessToken -RefreshToken $refreshToken -Resource https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com -Credential $credential -ServicePrincipal

Connect-PartnerCenter -AccessToken $pcToken.AccessToken -AccessTokenExpiresOn $pcToken.ExpiresOn -ApplicationId $appId
```

But I can't seem to retrieve the refresh token (first PS commands). When i execute the code I'll get Get-Credential login screen where I fill in my Client_ID and Client_secret. Afterwords I'll get a azure login page where I fill in my Credentials.
But I keep to get this error: 
[image]

Even when I add the URL "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/" in my Azure AD application settings, in the setting redirect URL's:
[image]

Is there some kind of permission I forgot to give to access the token ?
Or do I miss an obvious step  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by activating the pre build URL that need to be accessed.
[image]

The command doesn't give me any errors and the windows login window also suceeed but I still can't seem to fetch an access token. (I activated the allows a application to request a token function in the same settings of the Partner center)